# Optimize sql query which contains 'or'

Tags: mysql, indexing

Query:

```
select * from t where (a = '..' or a = '..') and b = '..'
```

Does this query use index (a,b)?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say? See the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

First, I would try rewriting this using `in`:

```
select *
from t
where a in ('..', '..') and b = '..';
```

Second, a better index would be `t(b, a)`.  There are no issues with `b` because it only appears once in the `where` clause with an `=`.

Third, if these don't speed the query, then use `union all`:

```
select *
from t
where a = '..' and b = '..'
union all
select *
from t
where a = '..' and b = '..';
```

This will get around the limitations on `where` clause optimization.

Comment: And upgrade to MySQL 5.6, because it [optimizes range predicates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mrr-optimization.html) better than earlier versions.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . Cool.  That would suggest that MySQL 5.6 *would* use the index `(a, b)` in this case.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it, but I assume an index on (b,a) would still be superior.